# Changing the size of this latex CV template from A4 to letter size

Tags: templates, geometry, paper-size

I have downloaded this CV template from [LatexTemplates](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-graduate-cv):

It uses a very very old library called  `res.cls` which can be found [here](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls).

The problem is that the size of this PDF is A4 and not letter size. I tried to change the following line :

```
\documentclass[margin, 10pt]{res} % added lettersize but no effect
```

also I tried to use the `geometry` package by adding:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@classoptionslist{<class options except `margin` OR empty>}
\makeatother
\documentclass[margin, 11pt]{res}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{1in}{0.6in}{0.55in}{0.10in}
```

but I think due to this line:

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} % Text width of the document
```

the package does not work properly.

I know I should probably not use this because of using the old `res.cls` library but at this point this is the one template that works for me. The only problem is that it changes the size to A4 and not letter size pages.

Can someone suggest a solution to resolve this issue?
thanks

[image: resume]
<sub>(source: [latextemplates.com](https://www.latextemplates.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/cv_2.png))</sub>

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\def\@classoptionslist{<class options except `margin` OR empty>}
\makeatother
\documentclass[margin, 11pt]{res}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{1in}{0.6in}{0.55in}{0.10in}

\usepackage{helvet} % Default font is the helvetica postscript font
%\usepackage{newcent} % To change the default font to the new century schoolbook postscript font uncomment this line and comment the one above

\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} % Text width of the document

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND ADDRESS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf John Smith} % Your name at the top
 
\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 1pt}\smallskip % Horizontal line after name; adjust line thickness by changing the '1pt'
 
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{123 Broadway} % Your address
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{City, State 12345}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{(000) 111-1111 or (111) 111-1112}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{resume}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
\section{OBJECTIVE}  

A position in the field of computers with special interests in business applications programming, information processing, and management systems. 


\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX Stackexchange. It is easier to help you if you add a minimum working example (code from \documentclass until \end{document}) that can be compiled. This way we can recreate the problem and then try to solve it.

Comment: @jens_bo I have added a sample code which compiles, the size of the page is `8.27*11.69 inch` which is A4 paper even after using `\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}`

Comment: [change font size latex "res" class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/551632)

Answer (score 1):

The `res` class is a LaTeX2.09 style that was ported to LaTeX2e. It is outdated. The same goes for package `anysize`.

If you still want to use `res`, remove package `anysize` and set the margins with package geometry.

I won't repeat any of the code you code, since it is badly outdated. Please consider to move to a more modern class. CTAN list [a couple of CV classes](http://ctan.org/topic/cv), commonly used are `moderncv`, `komacv` and `europecv`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, and decided that the answer given here is not good enough. The age of the `res` class should not make it unusable.

It turned out, the change to make for `a4paper` is quite simple: in `res.cls` change the block

```
\PassOptionsToClass{11pt,12pt}{article}
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
```

to

```
\PassOptionsToClass{11pt,12pt}{article}
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
\RequirePackage[a4paper]{geometry}
```

leaving everything else untouched, this produced cv pages as expected.

Comment: So basically, you are recommending the same. Using `geometry`. But you should do it in the preamble and not change the class.

Comment: @Johannes_B no, unfortunately changing the geometry in the preamble does not produce correct results. I haven't tracked down the issue, but it seems the class sets up some margins depending on the size of the paper, as present during initialization.